# reading json encoded php array using ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a php array with key, value pairs. I have json encoded it. And using ajax.Request i called the php file in which that array is there. Now i have to access both key and value pairs. Could anyone let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in javascript "json.js" is required. you can download this.

```
var votedCommentString = getCookie("votedComment"); // get value of voted comment cookie 

votedComment = JSON.parse(votedCommentString); // extract json object into array

votedComment[votedComment.length] = id; // add more data in array

var cookieData = JSON.stringify(votedComment); // convert array into json object

setCookie("votedComment", cookieData, 365); // and again set cookie
```

In PHP you can access this in following way

```
$cookieData = (array)json_decode($_COOKIE["votedComment"]); // extract json object into array

print_r($cookieData);
```

Use

```
json_encode($array_variable) // to convert array in to json
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON.

- [You can use the JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).
- You can use a library method like jQuery's `$.parseJSON()`.
- If the JSON is trusted, you can use `eval()`.

Comment: Don't use `eval`. It is slow and inefficient. Crockford's json2.js will use faster, native JSON parsers if available.

Comment: @David That's why I placed it last :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said the array is in php file which is called via ajax, you can simply decode the json encoded string and retrieve the array with keys and values respectively.

Simply use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to retrieve the array.